# How to force disable the modal or a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When my users are readOnly, I want to limit some access. In this case, the ability to edit notes. I can't explain why with this code, I still can open up my note when the user is readOnly

```
if(codeParam == '{{ $baby->readOnlyCode }}' ) {

    //I am in side this code 
    $("a.btn, .btn-link, #logNote, pre, .btn").click(function() {
        return false; 
    });
}
```

https://mybabies.app/baby/797b808a-e8c6-4a83-acf4-14ebe1f776b1?code=rithys4k

Please click on the note box, you will see that somehow it still be able to trigger.

[image]

I even tried added the check and return false in `showModal()`

```
function showModal(val, type, logId ) {

    console.log("val, type, logId",val, type, logId);


    if(codeParam == '{{ $baby->readOnlyCode }}' ) {
       return false; 
    }

    ...
```

or tried **preventDefault**

```
if(codeParam == '{{ $baby->readOnlyCode }}' ) {
    $("a.btn, .btn-link, #logNote, pre, .btn").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        return false; 
    });
}
```

If you spotted what I missed, please let me know.

Answer (score 5):

The problem you're having is you're attaching a second event listener that *only* returns false and prevents default, but the *first* event listener that pops the modal is still attached.

I.e.,

```js
$("a.btn").click(function(e) {
    alert("Hello World!");

});

$("a.btn").click(function(e) {
    return false; // this does nothing to the previously attached event listener

});
```

Possible solutions:

From inspecting your code, you have some options:

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#noteModal', function (e) {
    // move the check for the param here
    if(codeParam == 'rithys4k' ) {
        return false; 
    }
});
```

Or: Use `disabled` attributes on the buttons/links when in readonly mode.

To give you some more background - `$().click()` is really just shorthand for [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) on the click event

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `on method` with `suffix` in jQuery, [on jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

```js
const clickAction = (e) => {
    // do anything
}

$('.btn, pre').on('click.go', clickAction);
```

Use `off` to **remove events**, [off jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/off/)

```js
$('body').off("click.go", ".btn, pre");

// OR

$('body').off("click.go", ".btn, pre", clickAction);

// OR

$('.btn, pre').off("click.go");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can debug the event order like this: `$._data($("#logNote").get(0), "events");`. New events go to the end and executed from top to bottom. In your case all you need to do is remember the trigger function and remove/add it when needed, example:

```js
  const cbToggleNoteModal = () => $("#toggleNoteModal").click();
  // you have to store the cb in a variable

  $("#logNote").click(cbToggleNoteModal);

  // to disable the cb, just de-register the callback
  $("#logNote").off("click", cbToggleNoteModal);

  // and register it back when you need it
  $("#logNote").click(cbToggleNoteModal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this with css property `pointer-events: none;`

```
 $("a.btn, .btn-link, #logNote, pre, .btn").css('pointer-events', 'none');
```